# SAML2 SSO: AuthnContext Class Schemas: "PasswordProtectedTransport" vs "unspecified"

Tags: single-sign-on, metadata, saml, saml-2.0

## BACKGROUND:

My company is acting as the Service Provider to our clients that are the IDP. We use OpenAM, but our clients use ADFS or Shibboleth. We exchange metadata files for establishing federations, not URLS. A client asked why we require an AuthnContext class schema (specifically `PasswordProtectedTransport`), and not only do we not know why, we don't know how to change it or what that would mean.

## QUESTION:

What is the functional difference between using "`PasswordProtectedTransport`" vs "`unspecified`" for the `AuthnContextClassRef` in a SAML2 assertion?

We currently use `PasswordProtectedTransport` amongst all our clients, but no one at my company can tell me why we require this. If we remove it, the federation stops working with a 500 error and a "`NoAuthnContext`" in the SAML trace. We also don't understand that, as I was led to believe from SAML documentation that having a schema is optional for the authentication. Even so, I saw no explanation anywhere of what the implications of using "`unspecified`" would be.

I can’t find any thorough explanation or discussion anywhere about this topic and was hoping someone could elaborate for me, as I am struggling to find light on this.

Answer (score 16):

`RequestedAuthnContext` in a request is a mean for a SP to ask the IDP to authenticate the user with a specific authentication mechanism.
For example, if you specify `PasswordProtectedTransport` in your request, the IDP knows it has to authenticate the user through login/password, protected by SSL/TLS.
The IDP says in its response which mechanism it used to authenticate the user through `AuthnContextClassRef`.

`RequestedAuthnContext` in a request is optional, but `AuthnContextClassRef` in the assertion is mandatory as specified by the SAML schema (hence the 500 error you encountered).
Basically, the `unspecified` URN is used by the IDP to say "I don't want to tell you how I identified the user".
As a SP, you have the choice to accept that answer or reject it, if you want to ensure that the user is authenticated with a secure mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. So, to be certain I understand this correctly, let me reiterate what I believe this means (sorry for being so basic on the subject):

My company does want to ensure identities are protected by a un/pw authentication, and thus we use PasswordProtectedTransport as our reliable means of security. We aren't required by SAML standards to ask for this particular schema in the request, but our business needs say we do authenticate via un/pw and the SAML response requires something to be listed for the AuthnContextClassRef. Hence, we do it this way.